# Sort a single string in ascending and alphapetical order

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Scenerio:

I have a hidden field with the id; `hndSelectedSurface`. I extract the value of the Field into  a string(single word).
e.g.`MIBO` or `DCAB`. 
A need it to be sorted in alphabetical order i.e. `BIMO`or `ABCD`

I tried the `sort` Method But can't get it to work the way i want.
I need it to work in `jquery or javascript`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the shortest (maybe not the fastest though) way:

```
"MIBO".split("").sort().join("");  // "BIMO"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like;

```
yourString = yourString.split('').sort().join('');
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/4KNTt/)**